# Decompositions of elements of $GL_n(Z)$

Tags: group-theory

In the general linear group over *a field* $F$, every element of the group has a Bruhat decomposition
$$GL_n(F) =\bigcup_{w\in W} BwB$$
where $B$ is the subgroup of upper triangular matrices, and $W$, the group of permutation matrices.

**Question 1.** Instead of *field*, if we consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, then how long such a decomposition is possible (inside $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}))$?

**Question 2.** If the Bruhat decomposition is not possible for some elements, than what are those elements for which it is always possible?

**Question 3.** If Bruhat decomposition is not possible for some element, then what is (are) other decomposition of such elements?